# Looping through tags in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm stuck and could use a 'nudge'. I'm working with Selenium/Python for the first time and I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around a specific problem.

The crux of the issue is this. I have an unknown number of span classes I want to loop through. The XPATHs look like this :

```
/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]
/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]
/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]
```

So, I know what I need to do. I need to loop through each li, and grab the span[2].text . I can't seem to make it work.

Okay, so I sort of lied. I **did** make it work , but it's a hack job. Id rather do this the right way so I can begin to understand how to troubleshoot stuff like this in the future.

In each of the li's above...there is another span class.

```
/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/span[2]
/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/span[2]
/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/div[4]/span[2]
```

This span class is named "time". So, I saved the main section to a variable :

```
items = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div/ul")
```

Then, I searched for elements in that section by class name :

```
all_times = items.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"time")
```

Then, looped through each, and saved the text to an array.

```
for times in all_times:
    text = times.text
    timeRemaining.append(text)
```

So... Using the length of the array, I know how many values to expect. I can successfully loop through the xpaths.

```
xpath1 =  "/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div/section[1]/div/ul/li["
xpath2 =  "]/div/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]"
for i, line in enumerate(timeRemaining):
    i += 1
    xpath = xpath1 + str(i) + xpath2
    bin = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
    print (bin.text)
```

Again, I'd much rather loop through this field like I did for the time (I tried using class name, but its not returning any results)...but I'm stuck. Like...stuck stuck. Not looking for the answer, just a nudge in the right direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
rows = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(ec.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="table_ls"]//tbody//tr')))
for row in rows:
    date = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[1]').text
    closing_price = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[2]').text
    fluctuation_range = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[3]').text
```

I omitted a part and hope you can understand. "rows" represents the XPath for each row in the table,it is a list containing elements. While iterating through each row, perform operations on each cell in the row.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. This is fantastic. I didn't fully appreciate that you could find XPATH in that manner.

So, I created a variable called rows (like you did above). Then I looped through the rows variable and did a find(by XPATH) on each row in rows.

You're the best.

Comment: Thank you for your affirmation, If it is helpful to you, please accept this answer.   @DouglasHicks